# Periodic functions and Lyapunov exponents

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, lyapunov-exponents

Suppose $f(x)$ is periodic. Or even quasiperiodic. Does it follow that $f(x)$ has a zero top Lyapunov exponent? I'm thinking that if we say $f(x)$ is periodic, then $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$ as an example. This implies that $f$ is bounded and thus if we consider;
$$\lambda_{\mathrm{top}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\ln|f(x)|=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\ln|f(x+2\pi)|$$
This gives;
$$\lambda_{\mathrm{top}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln|f(x)|-\frac{1}{x}\ln|f(x+2\pi)|\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(0)=0$$
Is this correct? and wouldn't this extend to quasiperiodic functions too?

Comment: What is the connection of the first to the second equation? It reads as if you conclude from $a=b=c$ that $a=b-c=0$?

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is periodic, $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$ for example

Comment: That was not the problem. You should have gotten from the boundedness of $f$, most importantly also away from $0$, that the individual limits are zero. There is no need for further manipulations.

Comment: what is a "top Lyapunov exponent"? Do you mean the largest Lyapunov exponent? If so, then no: Lyapunov exponents are looking at how infinitesimal perturbations grow. The neighboring orbits of a limit-cycle cannot be closed (periodic), they either grow or decay, i.e. they either have a positive or negative Lyapunov exponent, depending on whether the limit-cycle is unstable or stable. In any case, your reasoning seems more suited to Floquet analysis, and indeed periodic orbits always have 1 Floquet multiplier that is 0 (perturbations along the flow).

Comment: @MATHBOI It might be good to add the definition of quasiperiodicity.